# Prevent OneSignal library from load twice at runtime

Tags: ios, cocoapods, onesignal

i'm trying to add OneSignal sdk to my project via cocoapods and then implementing the push notification module with NotificationServiceExtension.
My problem is when i run my project i have this warning **Already swizzled UIApplication.setDelegate. Make sure the OneSignal library wasn't loaded into the runtime twice!** and then i can't subscribe to OneSignal server.
I'm sure that the problem is coming from my pod file config because when i removed the OneSignal pod from **AppKit** the warning disappear and i can subscribe to the notification server, but i can't delete this pod from there because i need it later.
Here's my pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

def common_pods
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'RxSwift', '~> 5'
    pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 5'

end

def shared_one_signal_pod
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'OneSignal', '2.12.6'
end

use_frameworks!
target 'App' do

    common_pods
    shared_one_signal_pod

  target 'AppTestTests' do
    #inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'AppOneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end

target 'App_iOS' do

    common_pods

end

target 'AppKit' do
    common_pods

    pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 15.2.0'
    shared_one_signal_pod

end

target 'AppUIKit' do

    common_pods

end
```

As you can see my project is decomposed to 3 local framework (iOS, Kit, UIKit) and my App target. So is there  a way to make that pod load once at runtime ??